# Jquery show/hide div on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have a loop which outputs the following content...

```
<div class="item-title"><a href="">Title here</a></div>
   <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-body">
      Body Here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to HIDE .item-content on page load.

When you click the title, it should SHOW .item-content

When you click the title again, it should HIDE .item-content

The problem is that as my query loops through, it assigns EVERY article a class of .item-content so EVERY article opens and closes together.

How do I make it show each title ONLY opens the corresponding content and not every piece of article content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using this solution, as you can see below, using `$(this)` can solve you problem. As i read your question, you want to display the content without going/redirect to another page after click anchor link, then you should prevent it from redirect by adding `e.preventDefault();` code.  Hope this help:

```
$('.item-content').hide();
$(document).on('click','.item-title', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next('.item-content').toggle();
});
```

**Jsfiddle Link**

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vzauux8o/1/)

Comment: Hi there. This doesn't let me click the item title? How do i make .item-title a regular link?

Comment: What you mean by regular link. Because right now, it already react as a link but without redirect. Another solution is, you can remove `e.preventDefault();` and then put `#` at href attribute of anchor link.

Comment: well when i click the link - it just jumps back to the top of the page. nothing shows/hides.

Comment: That is why you need to use e.preventDefault() rather than use the #. See edited post with jsfiddle..

Comment: Thanks for your help. it still doesn't work and not sure why.

Comment: You see the fiddle link?? It must be the html structure of yours

Comment: i think you are right. if i dump your html in, it works, but mine still does nothing,

Comment: It must have culprit somewhere. Try to figure out line by line. Or you can post full code of html that you have on SO. The solutions provided here almost rely on what you ask and what you provided.

Comment: got it. stray div at bottom of page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73713/discussion-between-lowercase-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jLx12rx8/
Jquery:

```
$('.item-title').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('.item-content').toggle();    
});
```

html:

```
<div class="item-title"><a href="">title</a>
   <div class="item-content">
      <div class="item-body">
      Body Here
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item-content {
    display:none;
}
```

I assumed the content was meant to be a child of the title node as you didn't specify how a title and content node are meant to be linked.

EDIT: new jsfiddle with a node
http://jsfiddle.net/jLx12rx8/2/

Comment: this seems good. How do i manage the a/link on item title? What i mean is, I want the item-title to be a regular link.

Comment: @lowercase does the new version suit your aims?

Comment: You're sure you're clicking on the new version? ( http://jsfiddle.net/jLx12rx8/2/ ) . Remove the e.preventDefault() if you want the page the link is pointing to to show up.

Comment: just doesn't do anything. i click the title links and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct element to hide/show using the `find()` method:

```
$('.item-title').click(function () {
    var content = $(this).find('.item-content');

    content.toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the content, then set up a handler on the titles to open the corresponding content item inside it:

```
$('.item-content').hide();
$('.item-title')
   .on('click',function(e) {
      $(this).find('.item-content').toggle();
    });
```

Comment: It would, as long as the HTML structure never changes. But if he decides to change the layout he'd have to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initially hide all the item-content
    $('.item-content').hide();

    // Attach a click event to item-title
    $('.item-title').on('click', function () {
        //Find the next element having class item-content
        $(this).next('.item-content').toggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1wjpohkf/1/